# Create Multiple Threads in a for Loop in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a test client where I can specify the number of threads to create. I run a for loop based on the number selected by the user and start my threads. I store the threads in a List so that I can monitor/kill the threads at a later stage. When I run the loop, I can see that all the threads have ThreadState.Running. However, I always see fewer threads being created. Kindly Help

```
    private void btnReadMTNPServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisableTestButtons();
        SetValuesFromControls();
        ResetThreads();
        _metrics.Clear();
        _runTest = true;
        _keys = GetTestKeysList();

        for (var i = 0; i < _numClients; i++)
        {
            var index = i;
            TestThreads.Add(RunNamedPipeThread(index));
            AppendConsoleText(string.Format("ThreadState: {0}", TestThreads[index].ThreadState));
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        AppendConsoleText(string.Format("Starting {0} Clients. Each Reading {1} Keys", TestThreads.Count, nudTestReadKeyCount.Value));
    }


    private Thread RunNamedPipeThread(int i)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(RunNamedPipeServerTest)
        {
            Name = i.ToString("D3")
            //IsBackground = true
        };
        while (thread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running)
            thread.Start(i);
        return thread;
    }

private void RunNamedPipeServerTest(object i)
    {
        var id = (int)i;
        var iteration = 0;
        var list = new List<short>();
        var client = new PipeClient("DHM");
        {
            client.Start();
            while (_runTest)
            {
                var startTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
                foreach (var key in _keys.TakeWhile(key => _runTest))
                {
                    list.Add(client.GetValue(key));
                    if (_delayPerKey > 0)
                        Thread.Sleep(_delayPerKey);
                }
                var finishTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
                //Keep the client connected using KeepAlive.
                client.KeepAlive();
                _metrics.Add(new PerformanceMetric(id.ToString("D3"), startTimeStamp, finishTimeStamp));
                AppendConsoleText(string.Format("{3}:{0}:Start:{1}, Took {2} ms", id.ToString("D3"), startTimeStamp.ToString("mm:ss.ffff"), finishTimeStamp.Subtract(startTimeStamp).TotalMilliseconds, iteration++));
                //Wait before sending request for data.
                Thread.Sleep(_testFrequency);
            }
            client.Stop();
        }
        if (cbxDisplayValues.Checked)
            AppendConsoleText(string.Format("{0}", string.Join(",", list)));
    }


    private void ResetThreads()
    {
        if (TestThreads == null)
            TestThreads = new List<Thread>();
        _runTest = false;
        TestThreads.ForEach(t => t.Abort());
        TestThreads.Clear();
    }


    private void AppendConsoleText(string text)
    {
        if (txtConsole.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => txtConsole.AppendText(string.Format("{0}{1}", text, Environment.NewLine))));
        }
        else
        {
            txtConsole.AppendText(string.Format("{0}{1}", text, Environment.NewLine));
        }
    }
```

This is the result that I always see in the text box. There are 5 threads running but only 3 are writing out. This happens randomly though. Sometimes 5 write out as expected and sometimes they don't.

```
ThreadState: Running
ThreadState: Running
ThreadState: Running
ThreadState: Running
ThreadState: Running
Starting 5 Clients. Each Reading 1000 Keys
0:002:Start:53:55.5393, Took 187.4653 ms
0:003:Start:53:55.6331, Took 125.0191 ms
0:004:Start:53:55.7424, Took 109.4014 ms
1:002:Start:53:58.7539, Took 62.4642 ms
1:003:Start:53:58.7851, Took 62.5031 ms
1:004:Start:53:58.8789, Took 46.8898 ms
2:002:Start:54:01.8316, Took 62.4693 ms
2:003:Start:54:01.8629, Took 125.0298 ms
2:004:Start:54:01.9410, Took 93.7239 ms
3:002:Start:54:04.9149, Took 52.3515 ms
3:003:Start:54:04.9985, Took 62.5211 ms
3:004:Start:54:05.0454, Took 46.8765 ms
4:002:Start:54:07.9954, Took 46.77 ms
4:003:Start:54:08.0736, Took 46.7811 ms
4:004:Start:54:08.1203, Took 46.8748 ms
5:002:Start:54:11.0636, Took 46.7713 ms
5:003:Start:54:11.1417, Took 62.4283 ms
5:004:Start:54:11.1885, Took 46.8748 ms
6:002:Start:54:14.1308, Took 39.5712 ms
6:003:Start:54:14.2173, Took 54.1113 ms
6:004:Start:54:14.2486, Took 47.9687 ms
7:002:Start:54:17.1964, Took 51.7147 ms
7:003:Start:54:17.2795, Took 62.3954 ms
7:004:Start:54:17.3107, Took 46.8722 ms
8:002:Start:54:20.2644, Took 46.77 ms
8:003:Start:54:20.3581, Took 46.77 ms
8:004:Start:54:20.3738, Took 46.7721 ms
9:002:Start:54:23.3386, Took 46.77 ms
9:003:Start:54:23.4324, Took 46.7704 ms
9:004:Start:54:23.4480, Took 46.7969 ms
```

**Edit #1:**
What is happening is that 5 threads say they are running. however, if you see closely below the line that says 'Starting 5 Clients. Each Reading 1000 Keys' there are 3 entries for each iteration 0, 1, 2... every three seconds. I am expecting 5 as 5 threads are running.

As per @jackncoke, I did try using this instead of the for loop:

```
Parallel.For(0, _numClients, i => RunNamedPipeServerTest(i));
```

For some reason, it is creating only one thread.

Then I also tried:

```
Parallel.For(0, _numClients, i => RunNamedPipeThread(i));
```

this works, however it still does not create the right number of threads. Also, if you look at method *RunNamedPipeThread*, I am still explicitly creating the thread for *RunNamedPipeServerTest*.

Comment: I recently had to do something similar to this  and instead of managing all of the threads I used Parallel.ForEach Loop and Parallel.For Loop. It worked out great i am not sure if it is something you may want to consider. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The Parallel.ForEach loop here is too slow for what I am trying to do. I tried the Parallel.For loop an it does the same thing. Infact either of them are slow untill i explicitly create a thread for it. and ends up behaving the same way.

Comment: How can you talk about slow when your threads Sleep() ? And make your question more explicit. I see 5 threads starting, looks OK. What is the actual problem?

Comment: I couldn´t find whats wrong either. Parallel.For should do faster that that Thread creation abordage.

Comment: A common root cause for such behavior is errors going unnoticed.

Comment: I apologize if my question is not clear enough. Please see Edit #1 on the post for details.

Comment: Realized that I had a new thread being created inside client.Start() call. I commented out that part of code and now it works fine. I believe that new thread creation was causing something to snap some of the threads that were getting created. Basically what I had already works fine and so does the TPL.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than creating a ton of own threads. It takes care of the task and thread scheduling for you, and you can specify the maximum amount of threads to use by specifying [ParallelOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent the operation from eating up all of the system's resources.

On top of that make sure you are using a [Concurrent Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx). Those collections are optimized for scenarios such as yours, and allows you to (for the most part) not worry about lock contention, deadlocks and a plethora of other potential hazards.

> For some reason, it is creating only one thread.

While `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` **may** schedule multiple threads, it doesn't necessarily mean it always will, as the documentation states:

> Executes a for (For in Visual Basic) loop in which iterations **may run in parallel**.

Generally spoken, if you use a concurrent collection and the workload is paralellizable, the runtime will decide to throw multiple threads at it.

Comment: Well I know i want to run say "_numClients" threads. the work in the method that i am calling in each thread is independent of each other and can be done in parallel. Surprisingly Parallel.For is not doing the work, Since i just want to run a loop based on 0 to 5 counts, do i really need a concurrent collection? I will try translating my 0-5 enumerable into a concurrent dictionary and see if it works.

Comment: I tried 

            var tempDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < _numClients; i++)
            {
                tempDictionary.AddOrUpdate(i, i, (i1, i2) => i2);
            }

            Parallel.ForEach(tempDictionary, new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _numClients}, x => RunNamedPipeServerTest(x.Value)); as you mentioned, however, it does not create multiple threads.